# ¿Cómo evitar que datos iguales se me dupliquen después de hacer una llamada de ajax asíncrona?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

```
var contador = 0;
for (var a = 0; a < data1.length; a++) {
    if (data1[a].estatus != "0") {
        conter++;
        var hora = data1[a].fecha.substring(11, 16);
        var fecha = data1[a].fecha.substring(0, 10);

        switch (data1[a].tipomensaje) {
            case "1":
                $("#tblNotificaciones").append("<tr class='success'><td>" + data1[a].id + "</td><td>" + data1[a].emisor + "</td><td>" + hora + "</td><td>" + fecha + "</td><td>" + data1[a].mensaje + "</td></tr>");
                break;
            case "2":
                $("#tblNotificaciones").append("<tr class='alert alert-danger'><td>" + data1[a].id + "</td><td>" + data1[a].emisor + "</td><td>" + hora + "</td><td>" + fecha + "</td><td>" + data1[a].mensaje + "</td></tr>");
                break;
            case "3":
                $("#tblNotificaciones").append("<tr class='alert alert-info'><td>" + data1[a].id + "</td><td>" + data1[a].emisor + "</td><td>" + hora + "</td><td>" + fecha + "</td><td>" + data1[a].mensaje + "</td></tr>");
                break;
            case "4":
                $("#tblNotificaciones").append("<tr class='alert alert-warning'><td>" + data1[a].id + "</td><td>" + data1[a].emisor + "</td><td>" + hora + "</td><td>" + fecha + "</td><td>" + data1[a].mensaje + "</td></tr>");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Tengo el anterior código y después de que hago una llamada de ajax me trae unos mensajes. Dependiendo del tipo de mensaje me pintará el texto, es decir, si en la respuesta me vienen 4 mensajes de tipo 1,2,3,4 `(data[i].tipomensaje)`, me pinta correcto cada uno de esos mensajes en una tabla, pero como es asíncrona vuelve a hacer la llamada y me vuelve a traer esos mensajes y está bien eso porque es de un historial. El problema es que, si ya están los mensajes pintados en la tabla, cuando vuelve a hacer la llamada me vuelve a pintar los mismos abajo de los que ya están y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Como comentario, las notificaciones deberías de realizarlas con websockets y no sobre un settimeout en donde supongo estás haciendo cada cierto tiempo una llamada ajax.

Comment: Y bueno, si no quieres que tu elemento HTML en donde se imprimen tus notificaciones siga creciendo con cada llamada ajax, simplemente vacía el elemento antes de que hagas tus appends y muestre las alertas: `$("#tblNotificaciones").html('');`

Comment: una solucion alternativa, declara una variable global como bandera y verificar que el proceso ya envio o esta enviando

Comment: claro, use la forma de vaciar el html y después llenarlo de una vez, me sirvió mucho gracias.